# Redirect http to https in Yii2 .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess file which redirects my advanced Yii2 app to frontend index.php file for that there is already an .htaccess file. which has following lines..

**This is Right Now my .HTACCESS at root directory**

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
  <Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
  RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

now i searched internet and i found this if i want to redirect to https then i have to add this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

so i added like this....

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
  <Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
  RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

then it loads website withouat any js and css... and also it is in http. But content it requires should be in https.

I do understand it is because of my another rewrite statement. But i am not so expertise in it. Please mae some suggetion.

**Here this thing if it is alone it works perfect without any problem.**

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

**It will send my http to https. So it works perfact.**

**Or if this is alone**

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```

**This rule tells that execute index.php file from the [.htaccess Directory/frontend/web/] directory . Means execute frontend/web/index.php . Here it is very important to do this as this is as per the framework structure.**

So i have to **combine these two rules together** and build a .htaccess which will work for both scenario.

**CONCLUSION**

**So my .HTACESS should tell the server we have to run  [.HTACESS DIR/frontend/web/index.php] in https.**

**UPDATE TO QUESTION**

**this is the .htaccess under frontend/web/ folder where my index.php is**

**And this is at root/frontend/web folder where index.php exists.**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Do i have to add https thing here ?

Comment: it do not redirect main page to https ... it stays in http .. it also calls for resources in http... but resources are not allowed in http.. they are only allowed in https.

Comment: @anubhava  you can check http://iklyn.com/

Comment: yes it is working... and because of it creating issue.. may be two rewrite condition are conflicting with each other..!!

Comment: @anubhava  see this https://iklyn.com/ url works... here it redirects the page to my frontend app ..it is in other folder.. so .htaccess works... i have applied some wrong rules...   both rules are conflicting with each other

Comment: @anubhava yes it is not redirecting to https ...  It is only redirecting resources to https .. not to my php file...

Comment: Right but if above rule is working then `http://iklyn.com/` should become `https://iklyn.com/` so clearly either .htaccess or mod_rewrite is not enabled.

Comment: actually it conflicts... and other rule is for Yii2 app... and they both are conflicting...  thanks.. for giving your precious time...

Comment: @anubhava actually there is another rule ..  with RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  ruile it works correct ... no problem in that.. But after that there is another rule RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]  which is used to say that ... find the index.php file in frontend/web/ folder and execute that file. I am able to run one of this . 1 or 2 .. But i am not able to do both rules togather in .htaccess.

Comment: @anubhava i updated question to clear some doubts. I have to do it because of my framework structure..

Comment: Do you have any other .htaccess in your system as well? Like in `/frontend/` or in `/frontend/web/` ? Also comment out `RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]` rule and retest.

Comment: yes i do have...   ohk will test with  RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F] commenting this  @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava will add those as soon as possible.

Comment: @anubhava i updated my question with the .HTACESS in frontend/web/ folder.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You `root/frontend/web/.htaccess` should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /frontend/web/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Just remember that a sub-directory `.htaccess` always takes precedence over parent directory `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way might be setting the `on beforeRequest` event handler in `/config/web.php` like so:

```
...
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'on beforeRequest' => function ($event) {
    if(!Yii::$app->request->isSecureConnection){
        $url = Yii::$app->request->getAbsoluteUrl();
        $url = str_replace('http:', 'https:', $url);
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url);
        Yii::$app->end();
    }
},
...
```

Comment: i was finding a Yii2 way... that's nice...!!

Answer (score 2):

In root .htaccess when i put this. It also works for me.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to change the virtual host on port 80 (HTTP):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and then have a separate virtual host for port 443 (HTTPS).

Assuming a Debian(-fork) Linux server you'd have to put the above in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myname.conf`.
After you've done that use `sudo a2ensite myname.conf` (if this fails, you can create the symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` yourself, but try not to). Now restart apache with 'sudo service apache2 restart'.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's just a www > non-www redirect handling both HTTP and HTTPS, not what the OP is trying to do.